# Merge [math] and [mathematics] tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The [math](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) tag currently has 9 questions; [mathematics](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics) has 3.  I recommend merging [math](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) into [mathematics](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics), keeping the long form rather than vice versa, since Americans like to say "math" and British users prefer "maths".

Comment: In that case, should all of those be synonymized?  I don't have a high enough tag score in either of those tags, so a mod may have to do it.

Comment: I  made an attempt to merge these flags, and I crashed the site. :) Will try again later.

Comment: @WinstonEwert: [Don't cross the streams!](http://www.matthewsdiehl.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/crossing-marketing-streams.jpg).

Comment: The current pending suggestion for master [tag:math] ← synonym [tag:mathematics] is backwards from what I'd like to see, which is master [tag:mathematics] ← synonym [tag:math].

Comment: Has this dropped by the wayside? has this been completed?

Comment: I would like a second user to downvote [master math ← synonym mathematics](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/math/synonyms) so that I can propose the opposite relationship, which is master [tag:mathematics] ← synonym [tag:math]. (Also, Winston is no longer a moderator.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request completed, with [mathematics](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics) as the master tag of [math](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math).